# Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

Tags: ros, frame, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . i using solidworks to get urdf file .

in rviz i have this error : Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

how can i fix that error ????

it is my launch file :

```
 <launch>
  <arg name="model" />
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find wrist)/urdf/wrist.urdf" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="true" />
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
 <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find wrist)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
</launch>
```

it is  my urdf file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="wrist">
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="-0.0155222222222222 0.0506514619883041 -0.0711837607475986" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.161357633901786" />
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0"  iyz="0" izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/base_link.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material  name="">
        <color  rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/base_link.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="m2_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="1.73472347597681E-18 3.46944695195361E-18 -0.0748894348894349" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.0767176926006627" />
      <inertia  ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh  filename="package://wrist/meshes/m2_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material  name="">
        <color rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin  xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/m2_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="m2_1"  type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-0.0155222222222222 0.0225000000000004 0.0416514619883041" rpy="3.14159265358979 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="m2_1" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 -1" />
  </joint>
  <link name="4_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="5.20417042793042E-18 1.38777878078145E-17 0.0075" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.192949779317265" />
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0"  iyy="0" iyz="0"  izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/4_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color  rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh  filename="package://wrist/meshes/4_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="4_1" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="-0.0155222222222222 0.00750000000000036 0.0506514619883041" rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="4_1" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link name="m1_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="6.93889390390723E-18 0 0.0444256539427829" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.0916588444916701" />
      <inertia ixx="0"  ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0"  izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/m1_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/m1_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="m1_1" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="-0.071 0 0" rpy="-3.14159265358979 0 -1.5707963267949" />
    <parent link="4_1" />
    <child link="m1_1" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link name="m1_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 1.38777878078145E-17 0.0444256539427829" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.0916588444916702" />
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/m1_2.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material  name="">
        <color rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"  rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/m1_2.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="m1_2" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.071 0 0" rpy="-3.14159265358979 0 -1.5707963267949" />
    <parent link="4_1" />
    <child link="m1_2" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link name="5_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="-6.93889390390723E-18 0.0055562404711535 0.00849999999999999"  rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.0736873670600793" />
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/5_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/5_1.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="5_1" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="-0.04 0 0.052" rpy="-1.5707963267949 0 1.5707963267949" />
    <parent link="4_1" />
    <child link="5_1" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link name="5_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="-6.93889390390723E-18 0.00555624047115352 0.00850000000000001" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.0736873670600792" />
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0"  iyz="0" izz="0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/5_2.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.941176470588235 0.674509803921569 0.117647058823529 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://wrist/meshes/5_2.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="5_2" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.057 0 0.052" rpy="-1.5707963267949 0 1.5707963267949" />
    <parent link="4_1" />
    <child link="5_2" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
</robot>
```

in rviz i have this error :
***Fixed Frame [map] does not exist***

how can i fix that error ????
enter code here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249082/fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just load the robot, why should RVIZ know where in the map your robot is located? So either publish or define this transformation or just set the fixed frame to "base_link".

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0